# Run a formula based on another cells value?

Tags: formula

I'd like to run this formula

```
=COUNTIF(N29:N295,">85")-COUNTIF(N29:N295,">95")
```

but only when another cell has the value "93"

I've tried IF functions but I can't get the syntax correct. Can anyone help?

Comment: Can you show the IF function you tried to write? Also, can you confirm is this in Excel? If it is, you can tag it as such to make sure more relevant people can see your answer.

Comment: What's this? Excel? Please add the appropriate tag to indicate the language or tool you're using.

Answer (score 0):

You would likely benefit by switching to the [COUNTIFS function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/COUNTIFS-function-53C4DC8E-0E5B-4E32-93DF-9CA5E7DA89ED).

Assuming that 'another cell' is Z1 then,

```
=IF(Z1=93, COUNTIFS(N29:N295,">"&85, N29:N295,"<="&95), "")
```

If, on the other hand, you meant that the values in column Z had to be 93 then,

```
=COUNTIFS(N29:N295,">"&85, N29:N295,"<="&95, Z29:Z295, 93)
```